# Your kernels are unsigned. This system will fail to boot in a secure boot environment

Tags: kernel, 18.04, secure-boot

I've installed the mainline kernel 4.18 from here http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18/ using ubuntu 18.04

The packages are unsigned and now grub is complaining about it at each update.

```
E: Your kernels are unsigned. This system will fail to boot in a secure boot environment.
```

How can I make the message go away? Or get some 4.18 signed?

I am not looking into building my own kernel.

Comment: I don't want to build my own kernel.

Comment: Signing process is the same with mainline kernel and the mainline kernel is unsupported

Comment: Besides that this isn't a supported configuration, try turning off **secure boot** in your BIOS.

Answer (score 3):

My process for removing the unsigned kernel (forgot I had installed it?):

> ```
> $ uname -r
> 4.17.2-041702-generic
> ```

‍

> ```
> $ ls /boot/
> abi-4.15.0-23-generic             memtest86+.elf
> abi-4.15.0-34-generic             memtest86+_multiboot.bin
> abi-4.17.2-041702-generic         retpoline-4.15.0-23-generic
> config-4.15.0-23-generic          retpoline-4.15.0-34-generic
> config-4.15.0-34-generic          retpoline-4.17.2-041702-generic
> config-4.17.2-041702-generic      System.map-4.15.0-23-generic
> efi                               System.map-4.15.0-34-generic
> grub                              System.map-4.17.2-041702-generic
> initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic      vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic
> initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic      vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic
> initrd.img-4.17.2-041702-generic  vmlinuz-4.17.2-041702-generic
> memtest86+.bin
> ```

‍

> ```
> $ dpkg -S /boot/vmlinuz-4.17.2-041702-generic
> linux-image-unsigned-4.17.2-041702-generic: /boot/vmlinuz-4.17.2-041702-generic
> ```

‍

> ```
> $ dpkg --list | grep 4.17.2
> ii  linux-headers-4.17.2-041702                4.17.2-041702.201806160433                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.17.2
> ii  linux-image-unsigned-4.17.2-041702-generic 4.17.2-041702.201806160433                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.17.2 on 64 bit x86 SMP
> ii  linux-modules-4.17.2-041702-generic        4.17.2-041702.201806160433                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.17.2 on 64 bit x86 SMP
> ```

‍

> ```
> $ dpkg --list | grep 4.17.2 | awk '{print $2}'
> linux-headers-4.17.2-041702
> linux-image-unsigned-4.17.2-041702-generic
> linux-modules-4.17.2-041702-generic
> ```

‍

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg --list | grep 4.17.2 | awk '{print $2}')
> [sudo] password for alex:
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> The following packages will be REMOVED:
> linux-headers-4.17.2-041702* linux-image-unsigned-4.17.2-041702-generic*
> linux-modules-4.17.2-041702-generic*
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> 2 not fully installed or removed.
> After this operation, 308 MB disk space will be freed.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
> (Reading database ... 203507 files and directories currently installed.)
> Removing linux-headers-4.17.2-041702 (4.17.2-041702.201806160433) ...
> Removing linux-image-unsigned-4.17.2-041702-generic (4.17.2-041702.201806160433) ...
> W: Removing the running kernel
> I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic
> I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic
> /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
> update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.17.2-041702-generic
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I ended reverting to the default kernel from ubuntu and it all workend as expected.